# How to integration by parts with Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to do integration by parts when $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure. That this how to integrate by parts
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) d\mu(x).
\end{align}